# Extracting an unspecified number of dictionaries named after keys in dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, split, nested

Good Evening,

Trust that all is well.

**Objective**

I'm attempting to breakup a dictionary into separate dictionaries for each key; the values for each new dictionary would be blank. The dictionaries will be populated at a later stage with lists using the zip function.

**My attempt**

The initial list (list_towers) would contain a varying number of values and an unspecified number of duplicate values. The values, in the code below, have been limited for my question.

After removing all duplicate values, I'm left with a list (unique_towers) which is then zipped into a dictionary (unique_towers_dict). All keys have blank values.

I can't figure out a for loop to iterate through the unique_towers_dict to create a separate dictionary for each key.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

My commented code is below

```
from collections import OrderedDict


#The list in reality would have a varying number of values, and an unspecified number of duplicate values
list_towers = ["Tower1", "Tower1", "Tower2", "Tower3", "Tower3", "Tower4", "Tower5", "Tower5"]

print(f"Complete list of Tower values: {list_towers}\n") #prints list of towers; includes duplicates

unique_num_towers = len(set(list_towers)) #extract number of unique values in the set
print(f"Number of Unique Towers: {unique_num_towers}") #prints the unique number of towers

unique_towers = (set(list_towers)) #extracts a unique values from list_towers into the set unique_towers
unique_towers = list(unique_towers) #convert set unique_towers into a list
unique_towers.sort() #sort the list in ascending order
print(f"Names of unique towers in list: {unique_towers}\n")

unique_towers_dict = {} #create an empty dictionary unique_towers_dict
for unique_towers in zip(unique_towers): #assign the lists to the dict
    unique_towers_dict[unique_towers] = [] #assign unique_towers as key; values are empty


print(f"Nested Dictionary: {unique_towers_dict}") #print dictionary; shows empty values; keys are in ascending order

#I can't figure out a for loop to iterate through the unique_towers_dict to create a separate dictionary for each key
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this loop should get the correct answer:

```
d = {}
for x in unique_towers_dict.keys():
    d[x[0]] = {}

print ("\n", d)
```

Output

```
{'Tower1': {}, 'Tower2': {}, 'Tower3': {}, 'Tower4': {}, 'Tower5': {}}
```